# Error saving data for csv using R

Tags: r, save, export-to-csv

When using program R, an error appears. 
I wrote the following code.

```
txt <- readLines(file("test.csv"))

nouns <- sapply(txt, extractNoun, USE.NAMES = F)

head(unlist(nouns), 30)
tail(unlist(nouns), 30)

nouns2 <- unlist(nouns)
nouns <- Filter(function(x) {nchar(x) >= 2}, nouns2)

nouns <- gsub("지금", "", nouns)

show <-unlist(lapply(nouns,extractNoun))
showfrq<- data.frame(table(show),stringAsFactors=F)

aa<-as.matrix(showfrq)
write(aa, "test2.xls")
```

there is no error in script
but, when I look at the csv file, there are error in dividing sheet

[image]

I was expecting this

[image]

Why is this happening?
I am using R version 3.2.4
and windows 8 x64
excel version 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two immediate things you need to do: is to change your write function to `write.csv`. Also, use the filename "test2.csv".

It is not necessary to create the aa matrix before writing to .csv